# Is there a way to see the different HBase data version in HIVE

Tags: hive, hbase

I have integrated HIVE and HBase, and I have 2 versions of data for each Hbase table columns,see below for e.g.

```
get 'HBASE_SQOOP', '111_emp1',{COLUMN=> 'amitesh',VERSIONS=>2}
COLUMN CELL
 amitesh:f_name timestamp=1497365863181, value=Raj
 amitesh:f_name timestamp=1497365606380, value=dev
 amitesh:l_name timestamp=1497365863181, value=verma
 amitesh:l_name timestamp=1497365606380, value=saha
```

Is there a way to see these versions in HIVE as well?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there are no ways to see previous cell version, you can only access the latest timestamp. Hive hbase handler version 1.1.0 supports access to the latest timestamp of keyvalue and range query on timestamp, check [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-2828) for more details.

**e.g.**

```
create external table test(id string,f_name string,l_name string,ts timestamp) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('hbase.columns.mapping' = ':key,amitesh:f_name,cf:l_name,:timestamp') TBLPROPERTIES('hbase.table.name' = 'test_rs');
```

This version has limited supported to timestamp and the latest patch [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-8267) supports access to individual cell latest timestamp using `:timestamp:cf:[optional qualifier or qualifier prefix]`, it will be added the next release.